# (v5) Detect view change

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

In fullcalendar v5, the callback **viewDidMount** can be implemented and when a view is selected in the toolbar the callback is invoked; but when the user chooses between **timeGridWeek** and **timeGridDay** views, this callback is not invoked.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Why exactly do you want to detect this change? Perhaps there is a different way you can approach your overall requirement.

Comment: @ADyson, I am writing a plugin for Fullcalendar and the aurelia framework and in a demo application, I am saving user selections to persistent state so after refreshing the page the state stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into `datesSet` to get the view type and do something you wish to do from there.

```
datesSet(dateInfo) {
    
    var view = dateInfo.view;
    
    var viewType = view.type; // dayGridMonth / timeGridWeek / timeGridDay
    
}
```